# Sub menu items expanding further than the parent div element

Tags: css, menuitem

I have a jsfiddle showing my issue: [my issues](http://jsfiddle.net/neonate928/rsxbrb6h/). My option (menu links) are expanding further than the navigation nav div that contains the menu. I know it has to do with the padding on my  for each element but I don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated.

CSS code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.navigation, .navigation a {
    width:245px;
    background-color:#363636;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.navigation h3 {
    padding:8px 2px 0 2px;
    margin:0;
}
.navigation ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.navigation li {
    margin:0;
    display:list-item;
}
.deeper.parent {
    background-color:#292929;
    padding:10px 2px;
}
span.nav-header {
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
}
ul.nav-child li a {
    text-align:right;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 2px;
}
ul.nav-child a:hover, ul.nav-child a:focus {
    background-color:#4a4a4a;
}
```

Comment: Padding adds width, so you have to account for that.  A div that has `width: 20px` and `padding: 5px` will actually be 30px wide, the original 20px plus 5px on each side (20 + 5 + 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct! It is the padding that is causing your issue. So add this to your `ul.nav-child li a` style:

```
width: calc(245px - *The Padding*);
```

Where `*The Padding*` is the padding you have on that element. In your case, `4px`, so your code would come out to be:

```
ul.nav-child li a {
    width: calc(245px - 4px);
    text-align:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 2px;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f315wt3a/)

Comment: Should be minus 4px, not 8px (padding is 2px on each side, 2 + 2 = 4). And if you're going to use calc you might as well do `calc(100% - 4px)` so the width will be adjusted if the parent width changes, otherwise you could just say `241px`.  But I was never aware of the calc function, very useful!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need this to work on modern browsers, use box-sizing: border-box (http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

```
ul.nav-child li a {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:right;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 2px;
}
```